# How does one dilute sulphuric acid (1.28sg@25ºc 460g/L) to 3 M Sulphuric Acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions

Thanks for looking.

The extent of my research around the issue so far.

SA sg table but wrong temp 60f not 77f/25c 
http://www.sschemical.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Conversion_Table.pdf

From
http://www.csgnetwork.com/specificgravliqtable.html
Liquid                                 Temp     kg/cu.m
Sulphuric Acid 95% conc.    20 C    1839 
Water, pure                               4 C   1000.00

SG curve water, if per chance useful
https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-temperature-specific-gravity-d_1179.html

%(w/w) to molarity and molality question. On which basis I bought battery sulfuric as another supplier had other for same purpose which was 34.5% and in below link 40% came out to 5.9~ M
https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091019225041AASpTj4

Any help appreciated

Comment: To ask the first obviously question, how good does the dilution need to be? $\pm 10 \%, \pm 1 \%, \pm 0.1 \%$ and so on... // 1.28sg@25% is really an odd specification. Is the 25 supposed to be some temperature? Perhaps $\pu{^\circ C}$ ?

Comment: @MaxW Sorry, yes the 25 was meant to be the temp in C, have fixed now. Regards the accuracy I would like achieve a result suitable for testing for Vitamin C by iodine titration as described here 

https://www.thoughtco.com/vitamin-c-determination-by-iodine-titration-606322

Really appreciate your response.

Comment: For that $\pm 10 \%$ would be fine. Just make enough to do standard and samples with same batch of diluted sulfuric acid. // See this [table](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/indsulfuric-acid-density-d_2163.html) that shows density doesn't change very much with temperature. So use $\pu{66 ^\circ F}$ densities and assume that they are good for $\pu{77 ^\circ F}$ which is waht you seem to want. Does that solve your problem, or do you need more help?

Comment: Great Thanks MaxW. Um, armed with that I think i could just use one of the solutions on the answers.yahoo page but which one to use IDK, they seem to come up with different answers. Sorry for the trouble. Thanks again.

Comment: @PeteBottom For future reference, I recommend you take a tour on how to type units along the widely consented guidelines by IUPAC and IUPAP.  There are compilations on ChemSE meta (e.g., https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know/3045#3045) showing how to achieve this here as well in either question, answer, or comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sulfuric acid has $\pu{460 g } \ce{H2SO4}\pu{/L}$ then the molarity of sulfuric acid is:

$\dfrac{\pu{460 g/L}}{\pu{98 g/mole}}= \pu{4.69 molar}$

As Alex pointed out for dilution  to 3 M Sulphuric

$C_1\cdot V_1 = C_2\cdot V_2$

$4.69\cdot V_1 = \pu{3 molar}\cdot \pu{1.00 L}$

$ V_1 = \dfrac{3}{4.69}\pu{ L} = \pu{0.640 L}$

So take $\pu{640 ml}$ of your concentrated sulfuric acid and dilute to 1.00 Liter.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not 100% sure if this will apply but you can probably use the formula C1V1 = C2V2. 
V1 being the volume of stock solution needed to make the new solution, C1 The concentration of stock solution, V2 The final volume of new solution, C2 The final concentration of new solution

For example 5 mL of a 0.25 M solution from a 1 M solution, using the formula plug values in => (V1)(1 M) = (5 mL)(0.25 M). Rearrange a bit =>  V1 = [(5 mL)(0.25 M)] / (1 M)V1 = 1.25 mL and after some quick calculations you should get something like this => 1.25 mL of the 1 M solution into V1-V2 = 5 mL – 1.25 mL = 3.75 mL of dilute.

Sorry if it isn't what you need.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your response. I will try to get my head around it anyway but I just thought to mention I had a critical error in the subject/question. I had 25% instead of 25 degrees C. I'm too much of a novice to know whether your response helps straight up, my instinct says, my error was unlikely to let you actually know the real query I had, but I will go over it a bit more. My response to MaxW above mentions the context for my desired result, ie 

https://www.thoughtco.com/vitamin-c-determination-by-iodine-titration-606322

Thanks again very much for your help in any case.